# Does the yyyymmdd.hhmmss date time-format have a name?

Tags: date, time, encoding, datetime-format, terminology

Discussing data time-formats, someone mentioned to me how he stores datetime (in a human-readable format) using floats as `yyyymmdd.hhmmss`, so `2019-09-18, 11:29:30am` would become `20190918.112930`

I'm trying to find out if this guy has invented his own format or if it is used (and described) elsewhere too - and if so, how is it even called...?

Comment: Where is this stored (database, file?) and is there a reason given? Based on a quick lookup, it seems both require 8 bytes in sql

Comment: Unfortunately the conversation had a different focus at the time and he did not go into details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It’s probably homespun**

I have seen a lot of date and time formats, and I have not seen this one before. My go is that his guy or his organization invented it themselves.

**Edit:** Thank you for confirming in the comment. Since comments are not always permanent on Stack Overflow, I quote here, you said:

> Finally got confirmation from the source: it's homespun indeed.

As an aside I don’t like it. A `float` is stored in a binary format internally, and only after formatting it into decimal does it become human readable. Using a `float` for a “human readable” date and time was not what formatting of floating-point numbers was meant for, it’s a hack.

**Use ISO 8601**

For a human-readable format I recommend ISO 8601. Here `2019-09-18, 11:29:30am` becomes `2019-09-18T11:29:30`. Or even better and still within ISO 8601, convert to UTC and append a `Z` to denote UTC. So if your original time was in Europe/Berlin time zone, it would become `2019-09-18T09:29:30Z`. As you can see, ISO 8601 is even more human readable than you friend’s format, and it is sortable as strings (as long as the years don’t go beyond 9999).

Comment: Finally got confirmation from the source: it's homespun indeed. Interesting discussion, thanks for all the contributions :-)

Comment: However, OP's format uses less than 40% of the memory usage of an ISO 8601 string.

Comment: - which shouldn't be a consideration until we know for a fact that the app has too big of a memory footprint. @Adám

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia, this would be similar to the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), which permits, all of the following for date and time combined:

- 2019-09-18T09:18:26+00:00
- 2019-09-18T09:18:26Z
- 20190918T091826Z

except that the `T` to separate the time from the date is replaced by `.` and the time-zone information is dropped.

That specific format has limited popularity either in the [`yyyymmdd.HHMMSS`](https://www.google.com/search?&q=%22yyyymmdd.HHMMSS%22) or the C's [`strftime()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strftime.htm)-compatible [`%Y%m%d.%H%M%S`](https://www.google.com/search?&q=%22%25Y%25m%25d.%25H%25M%25S%22) form.

---

## EDIT

As far as using `float` for date and time the way you suggests, it depends on the precision and [machine representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Internal_representation).
If the system is following [IEEE 754 basic standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats) (which is what most modern C compiler stick to), you would need at least `float64`.

However, it is not common to do so.
This might be in part because it may be difficult to correctly predict the accuracy of the time information, and it is not as bit-efficient as the [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).
Given that the only positive feature it has is that it can rely on standard `%f` from [`sprintf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/), I would only see it advantageous when [`strftime()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/?kw=strftime) is not available or a performance bottleneck.

Comment: But notice that he **stores** dates in this format, it's not used for output to the user (though it simplifies debugging, of course) So I'm really looking into this approach of storing dates as floats.

Comment: @MBaas aside that you would need a `float64` you could do it that way, but it is not common to do so.

Answer (score 1):

While he may have come up with it himself, it is also a formatting option in [`zipinfo`](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/zipinfo.htm).

The [manual](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzcxT6EqsyAzLy1foUYhvSi1QEHXUcFIISU1OTM3Mef/fwA) doesn't explicitly name it, but describes it as *a sortable decimal format* and *decimal format*.

Comment: Good catch. The way I read the info in your link, zipinfo uses two-digit year, though, so `190918.112930` (not `20190918.112930`).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if we are talking about SQL date format. If so, this date format is present in SQL Statements.
Not sure about the name, it's called in different ways: non-standard, ISO, Other format and so on.
Is present also in PHP.